# How to iterate from first row of excel and try to login and then again iterate to second row and try to login again using Selenium with POI?

Tags: java, selenium, apache-poi

My scenario is I have an excel with three rows and two columns. First Column is User Name and second column is Password and under which three rows with some data exists.

My target is my webdriver script reads the first row data and tries to login then reads the second row data and again try to login and so on.
The script I have create is it reads first username and put it in the user Name text box and reads first password and put in password and then try to login and never goes to second row data. My guess is the break I used in the script is not at correct place
I dont know where I should break the the loop to go from row to row.

Here is my code:

```
FileInputStream loginFile = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Selenium\\Input_Data\\LoginFailure.xlsx"));

//Get the workbook instance for xlsx file
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(loginFile);

//Get the first sheet of the xlsx file
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Login");

//Iterate through each row from first sheet
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

while (rowIterator.hasNext())
{
    Row row = rowIterator.next();

    //For each row iterate through each columns
    Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext())
    {

        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        if(cell.getColumnIndex()==0)
        {
            driver.findElement (By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
        else 
            driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }
        break;          
}

driver.findElement(By.id("LoginButton")).click();
System.out.println("**********User login failure**********");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting break ..Can you please try to put continue and let me know the results.

break will go out of the loop.However, continue will go to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You should break out of the `cellIterator` after you got your `username` and `password` in order to continue with the outer loop for the rows.

```
while (cellIterator.hasNext())
{
    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

    if(cell.getColumnIndex() == 0)
    {
        driver.findElement (By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
    }
    else
    {
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
    }

    if(cell.getColumnIndex() > 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Previous scenario was to read data from  excel sheet but now I want to write the result back to same excel sheet. The flow I am trying to achieve is read user name and password from excel and enter it in the web from and as per pass or fail (which I will verify by user logged in successful message or user login failure message IDs) the same result should be entered into excel sheet. My excel sheet will have multiple username and passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Break the inner while loop when you get both username and password.

```
while (rowIterator.hasNext())
{
    Row row = rowIterator.next();

    //For each row iterate through each columns
    Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext())
    {

        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        if(cell.getColumnIndex()==0)
        {
            driver.findElement (By.id("UserName")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==1){
            driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys(cell.getStringCellValue());
        }else{
        break; 
        }         
    }
  driver.findElement(By.id("LoginButton")).click();
}
```